# custom input format for hashcat

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, hashcat

I am doing a password strength audit (I have permission). I'm using Hashcat.  It supports formats like `sha-256(password.salt)` and `sha-256(salt.password)` but my hashes are generated by `sha-256(username+"|"+password+"|"+salt)`.

So, ideally:

1. I would provide a file in the format `username,salt,hash`
2. hashcat would concatenate `username, [password guess], salt`,
3. hashcat would hash that string and compare it to the hash.

Is there a tool in hashcat that helps me define how the parts of the hash are concatenated, to add to the algorithm options provided?

Answer (score 3):

Hashcat supports rules for [modifying word lists on the fly](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack).

You can prepend the username and append the salt in a rule file (save as `something.rule`):

```
^username $salt
```

and use `-r` in Hashcat to call the rule file.

Comment: hashcat's append/prepend rules are actually one character at a time. So this would be something more like 

    ^e ^m ^a ^n ^r ^e ^s ^u ^| $| $s $a $l $t.